# Chat comet site using python and twisted

Tags: python, twisted, orbited

i want to build a site similar to www.omegle.com. can any one suggest me some ideas.
I think its built usning twisted , orbiter comet server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twisted is a good choice. I used it a few years ago to build a server for a browser-based online game I wrote - it kept track of clients, served them replies to Ajax requests, and used HTML5 Server-Sent DOM Events as well. Worked rather painlessly thanks to Twisted's good HTTP library.

For a Python web framework, I personally favor Django. It's quick to get going with it, and it has a lot of functionality out of the box ("batteries included" as it says on their site I think). Pylons is another popular choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Nevow](http://www.divmod.org/trac/wiki/DivmodNevow), which is a web framework that is built on top of [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/).  The documentation for Nevow includes a fully functional [two-way chat application](http://divmod.org/trac/browser/trunk/Nevow/doc/howto/chattutorial/index.xhtml?rev=16627) including examples of how to write [unit tests](http://divmod.org/trac/browser/trunk/Nevow/nevow/test/test_howtolistings.py#L175) for it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use Twisted. ;) It has both chat clients and chat servers. Then you also need a web framework. I'd use either Grok or BFD, but there are many Python Web Frameworks around, and few of them are really bad.

Answer (score 1):

Most XMPP servers support [BOSH](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html).  If you use the [strophe javascript library](http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/), you have only to worry about presentation -- the rest is done for you.

Answer (score 1):

Because you seem to be looking for both Comet functionality and a Web Framework, you might have a look here: http://github.com/clemesha/hotdot which is a complete example of combining Django, Orbited, and Twisted.